# cex.axis only affects y-axis, not x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I made a plot of the factor variable "answer" in subset A1. I want to decrease the text size on both axes, in order to fit in both extreme values on the x-axis. However, **when using cex.axis, only the font size on the y-label is affected**, not on the x-axis. Why is that, and how can I change that?

The function I used is:

```
plot(A1$answer, main = "Would you recommend edX to a friend of you?", xlab = "Answer", ylab = "#students", col='lightblue', cex.axis=0.75, font=3, family='mono'); box(col='lightblue');
```

And this is the output:

[image: edX recommendation]

Comment: What class is `A1$answer`? Any chance you used `barplot` instead of `plot`? In this case try `cex.names = 0.75`

Comment: A1$answer is ordinal factor level. // barplot I tried already - gives the error 'height' must be a vector or matrix'

Answer (score 8):

When you use `plot` on a `factor` variable `x` it calls `barplot` by default (or to be more precise `barplot(table(x))`, i.e you can look into `?barplot` for hints. In this case, as I mentioned in the comments, the `x-axis` is considered as labels, not a numeric axis, therefore you need to use `cex.names` like so:

```
tab <- as.ordered(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
plot(tab, cex.axis = 0.75, cex.names = 0.75)
```

Also, as hinted above, if you want to use `barplot` directly, you need to make a table first

```
barplot(table(tab), cex.axis = 0.75, cex.names = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the barchart function in lattice, and this has a much better output:

[image: This is better]

Comment: but I now see it does not answer the question. Just provides an alternative.